# In how many ways can 6 cookies be given to 4 students?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways 6 cookies be given to 4 students, where each student is eligible for any number of cookies (including zero) ?
Can someone please tell me how to go about in solving a sum like this?

Comment: This was asked a few hours ago. Can anyone find the duplicate? Perhaps the OP asked it, deleted it and reposted it.

Comment: It depends on whether the cookies are identical or not. If identical, see the wikipedia article on Stars and Bars. Also, same question was asked on MSE less than $24$ hours ago.

Comment: Yes I had asked this question before but since very few people replyed i thought i'd repost it so more people could see it

Comment: I did look at the wikipedia article, though i didn't understand it completely then I tried using the formulae which gave me a result that didn't match with answer at the back of the book.

Comment: I can't add a comment as I do not have enough rep. I would recommend watching: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEul6TMYDY0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_6\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_4\}$ two sets then number of maps $$f\colon A\rightarrow B$$
is 
$$\#B^{\#A}=4^6$$ 
What's the relation of this result with your case?

Comment: Wow yes that is the answer!

Comment: But what exactly is the reason for it? Should i think in terms of  each cookie having a choice of going to any of the 4 student?

Comment: That is exactly correct.  It assumes the cookies are distinct, so it matters which cookie a given student gets.